# Why does to_datetime result in an error when not assigning to a column, but variable?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code:

```
example = {'date': ['01_September_2020_abdca', '01_September_2020_sfasd'],
          'user': ['a', 'b']}

example_df = pd.DataFrame(example)
test = example_df['date'].str.extract('([0-3][0-9]_[a-zA-Z]*_[0-9]{4})')
display(pd.to_datetime(test, format='%d_%B_%Y'))
```

However, this results in an error, namely "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'". But, if I change the code into an assignment to a column, then it works:

```
example = {'date': ['01_September_2020_abdca', '01_September_2020_sfasd'],
          'user': ['a', 'b']}

example_df = pd.DataFrame(example)
example_df['date_datetime'] = example_df['date'].str.extract('([0-3][0-9]_[a-zA-Z]*_[0-9]{4})')
display(pd.to_datetime(example_df['date_datetime'], format='%d_%B_%Y'))
```

Can someone explain to me why these two pieces of code are not equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `test = example_df['date'].str.extract('([0-3][0-9]_[a-zA-Z]*_[0-9]{4})')`, `test` becomes the dataframe.

`pd.to_datetime` expects a dataframe's column.

From [`pd.to_datetime docs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

> arg int, float, str, datetime, list, tuple, 1-d array, Series DataFrame/dict-like
>   The object to convert to a datetime.

Do this instead:

```
In [2670]: pd.to_datetime(test[0], format='%d_%B_%Y')
Out[2670]: 
0   2020-09-01
1   2020-09-01
```

And when you do `example_df['date_datetime'] = example_df['date'].str.extract('([0-3][0-9]_[a-zA-Z]*_[0-9]{4})')`,

you are adding a column by `date_datetime` in the dataframe `example_df`.

And you run `pd.to_datetime` on the column itself. Hence it works.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is:

```
pd.to_datetime(test, format='%d_%B_%Y')
```

Since `test` is DataFrame, while `pd.to_datetime` only accepts Series/1D-array. This works fine though:

```
display(pd.to_datetime(test[0], format='%d_%B_%Y'))
```

Or

```
display(test.apply(pd.to_datetime, format='%d_%B_%Y'))
```